# How to get children on the first layer from a Firebase reference? (shallow query)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase Database structure that looks like this:

```
/users
    - abc001
        - name: "Harry Watson"
        - credentials: 
            - email: "h.watson@yahoo.com"
    - abc002
        - name: "Jason Polakow"
            - credentials: 
                - email: "j.polakow_1@gmail.com"
    - abc003
        - name: "Madeleine Février"
        - credentials: 
            - email: "mad_fev@gmail.fr"
    - ...
```

I would like to get all children on the first layer, e.g.:

```
- abc001
- abc002
- abc003
...
```

- I don't know how to do this. As far as I know, a `value` event would also trigger for every child of every child (second and third layer).
- A `childAdded` event is also not the right choice, because I only want to receive the data once (I don't want to listen for data changes/child added, ...).
- A single-event of `childAdded` only triggers once and returns the first child (`abc001`).

Could you help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with your data structure.  Firebase Realtime Database doesn't have "shallow queries".  When you listen to a location, you get all of its nested data all of the time.  There are [no plans](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/124) to change this.

You could instead create a new location in your database that contains just the data you're looking for.  It's common to duplicate data like this in NoSQL databases.  You just have to remember to keep all the duplicates up to date any time one of them needs to change.

Comment: But it would be possible to get all the keys (`abc001`, ...) **with** the user information? My problem is that I only want to fetch the data once, it does not matter whether I get all the credentials, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  This sounds like something different than you originally asked?

Comment: It shouldn't be different. Can I just get all keys (`abc001`, ...) in an array or something like this? @DougStevenson

Comment: In my answer, I said it's not possible to get only those keys and nothing else, because queries are not shallow.  If you add an observer to `/users`, you will get all the data under that location every time.

Comment: So if I would add a `childAdded` listener, there is no way to only get all users once? (It's ok if I also get the underlaying data; credentials etc., not only those keys)

Comment: @T.Meyer What Doug is telling you is that you can get ALL the data and not just the keys, for example. So if you do ref.child("users").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in... you will get your entire tree only once. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#read_data_once

Comment: Thanks. So this snapshot would have a property called "children". Would the number of children be the number of users or would every child be a child of that snapshot? I'm sorry if this is confusing, I'm trying my best to make it as clear as possible.. EDIT: So would every child of the snapshot be a user? @RenaudTarnec

Comment: @T.Meyer snapshot.value will represent the entire tree under the "users" node and it is up to you to write the code to go through the tree. Note that getting such a full tree may not be very efficient, but it is what you asked! :-)

Comment: Yeah, but would every snapshot.children (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDataSnapshot#/c:objc(cs)FIRDataSnapshot(py)children) child be a user? So if I would iterate over snapshot.children, would every child be a user (with its child nodes)? @RenaudTarnec

Comment: @DougStevenson Doing a shallow query actually is possible but as far as i know it can only be done with the REST API ([see the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#shallow))

Comment: @AndréKool That's kind of out of scope, since the OP is specifically talking about swift.  The mobile client libraries don't support this for technical reasons.